# bug in kotlin annotation?

Tags: android, annotations, kotlin

here are two code examples

java:

```
public class Q {

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
    @IntDef({LOL.one, LOL.two})
    @interface Lol{}

    public final class LOL{
        public final static int one = 1;
        public final static int two = 2;
    }

    public Q(){
        q(1);
    }

    void q (@Lol int q){

    }
}
```

kotlin:

```
class Q {

    @Retention(AnnotationRetention.SOURCE)
    @IntDef(LOL.one, LOL.two)
    internal annotation class Lol

    object LOL {
        const val one = 1L
        const val two = 2L
    }

    init {
        q(1)
    }

    internal fun q(@Lol q: Int) {

    }
}
```

probleb here: in java calling this **q(1);** will show you an error like :"must be one of..."

but in kotlin there are no any error message, so we can put as parameter any long we want... so we lose advantages of annotation as parameter...

looks like a bug or I am dooing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a bug. This is a feature that is not yet implement in Kotlin. It is planned in the future.

Comment: not implemented feature that right now looks like a bug :)
but still thanks for answering! will be waiting for updates!

Comment: @AndriyAntonov Technically, this is not a bug because it is just a lint checking at compile time. It depends on the IDE to support it.